# Регулярные выражения в Excel

Tags: регулярные-выражения, excel

Имеется такая таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как отделить цифры в начале строк при помощи регулярных выражений?
С начала строки до знака "/"

Comment: [Анализ текста регулярными выражениями (RegExp) в Excel](https://www.planetaexcel.ru/techniques/7/4844/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте функцию `поиск`: `=ЛЕВСИМВ(A1;ПОИСК("/";A1;1)-1)`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос @bakusite: и где здесь регулярные выражения, которые Вы хотели? :)